# Prove: For any integers $p$ and $q$, if $p$ is odd and $q$ is even, then $8p + 5q − 7$ is odd.

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

Is this proof done correctly?

$8(2k+1)+5(2k)-7 = 2k+1$

$16k+8+10k-7=2k+1$

$26k+1 = 2k+1$

One of our hints says:

> An integer $n$ is a multiple of $a$ iff $n = ak$ for some integer $k$. (When $a = 2$, this is exactly the definition of even.)

But I don't understand how that might apply to what I've done above.

Comment: $q=2j\implies 8p+5q-7 = 2(4p+5j-4) + 1$

Comment: To use an approach like yours you should use $p=2k+1$ and $q=2l$.  You are  using $k$ to denote integers that are not necessarily equal.

Comment: To repeat @AndréNicolas's point, the answer to "Is this proof done correctly?" as it is currently written is "no, but it could be fixed by using different names for potentially different quantities."  (Also, your teacher may or may not—but I think should!—object to your beginning, rather than ending, with the desired equality.  In this case it is nearly harmless since all steps are reversible, but this is not always the case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For any integer $p,q$

$$8p+5q-7=2(4p+2p-3)+q-1\equiv q-1\pmod2$$ which will be odd

$\iff q-1$ is odd $\iff q$ is even